# What's a good icon to represent Rewards Points?

Tags: icons

I'm working on the design for a loyalty program (points-for-rewards system) for a startup. I'm thinking of treating the points as a form of currency. Some companies prefer to append the $ sign to the points, but it might be too confusing for the customers.

What's a good icon to represent the points? So far, I've have the ff. ideas:

- Star
- Medallion/Grail
- Ribbon
- "RP"
- Stack of coins
- Coin

Answer (score 1):

I will choose either stack of coins, or better a coin with digits indicating how much points the user earned .

I think medallions and ribbons are not suitable for the purpose you described , but if you have stages in the rewarding system, like "after x points the becomes/deserves  y" then you can use them to flag the transition to the new state.

Best

Answer (score 1):

Reward points are very similar to Cents and Dollars which are **accumulated over time to Redeem** for a gift or to make a new purchase.

So, using an icon like these would make more sense:

[image]

Comment: The piggy bank is a good icon in my opinion. But the dollar sign in the coin above it is not preferable in my opinion, as even though reward points can be exchanged for gift items or discounts depending on the scheme, they don't directly correlate to paper money. Hence, I'd rather prefer a blank golden yellow coin in its place.

Comment: @ikartik90 They do directly correlate to paper money. I use citibank credit card and I use the reward points to make any purchase which is equal to paper money.

Comment: I don't contest the fact that it is equivalent to paper money in terms of monetary value but can you trade it at grocery stores to buy daily utilities?

Answer (score 1):

I think using money is too literal and specific and because of this the suggestions so far do not shout out "REWARD" when first viewed but rather savings or something to do with a bank.

I live in the UK and there are many generic reward schemes but one of the most prevalent is [Nectar](https://www.nectar.com) (Nectar is a sweet reward for bees). 30 years ago people in the UK when they saw the word Nectar would probably not associate it with a reward of any kind, but now, i would hazard a guess that a very large slice of the population would and that is from brand recognition and extensive marketing.

I guess, what I'm saying is you don't need to go straight to the money analogies, you can pick something more abstract. How about a Carrot? The Carrot and the stick story has been knocking around for a while? Does the donkey get the carrot as a reward or the stick as punishment? I think its well known enough that you could perhaps use it.

"You've collected 50 Golden Carrots! Redeem"

You could even have a play on words like Carat as in the unit of mass used to measure the purity of gold.

[image]

I'm not suggesting you run with the Carrot idea, its just an "outside the box" thinking exercise and I hope gets you away from literal analogies.

Answer (score 0):

Using the icon of actual currency (such as dollars) might be confusing.

The fact is, it's just virtual currency you're handing out, so you should relate the currency to what the website is related to. Making it personal and related to the brand or website will make it easier for the users to understand and even give them a sense of wanting to earn more, as if it's a game.

Let's say it's a shoe company; *let people earn shoelaces.*

Is it a webshop for sports clothing? *let the users earn tennis balls?*

**I'm just giving idea's of what I'm talking about here, hope you get the idea. Make your own currency.**